# Query for user roles and their skills

Tags: meta-query, user-meta, users

I am trying to get all those users having role as candidate and 3 skills as follows. `skill a, skill x, skill e`. Only want three users, What I am missing

```
$args = array(

    'role' => 'candidate',
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
    'key' => 'as_skills',
    'value' => array('skilla','skillx','skille'),
    'compare' => '='
       ),
     ),
 );

$test = get_users($args);   


echo "<pre>";
print_r($test);
echo "</pre>";
```

getting no data, but data is there for sure.

Comment: According to codex: value (string|array) - Custom field value. It can be an array only when compare is 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', or 'NOT BETWEEN'. Also, do all _candidate_ users have all the 3 "skill"?

Comment: what should I do for value in this situation ?

Comment: for the candidates only want those who has any one of these skills, and they are stored in json form in meta value

Answer (score 0):

There is one small issue. You have to user `'IN'` instead of `=` because you want to check values with array

```
$args = array(

    'role' => 'candidate',
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
    'key' => 'as_skills',
    'value' => array('skilla','skillx','skille'),
    'compare' => 'IN'
       ),
     ),
 );

$test = get_users($args);   


echo "<pre>";
print_r($test);
echo "</pre>";
```